# Google Apis Invalid grant Bad Request

Tags: php, api, refresh-token

I get this error in PHP when trying to connect a WEB application:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" } in /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(103): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse() #1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute() #2 /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Task/Runner.php(182): call_user_func_array() #3 /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(66): Google\Task\Runner->run() #4 /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(922): Google\Http\REST::execute() #5 /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Service/Resource.php(238): Google\Client->execute() #6 /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/g in /var/www/vhosts/kabengestiondeagendas.com/httpdocs/cada/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php on line 128`

I think the error is in this piece of code in PHP:

```
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) 
    {
        // the new access token comes with a refresh token as well
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($TOKEN_FILE, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Its probably your refreshToken which is invalid and thus cannot be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to revoke the accestoken with the following code:

```
    session_start();    
    $accesstoken=$_SESSION['access_token'];

    //Unset token and user data from session    
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);    
    unset($_SESSION['userData']);    

    //Reset OAuth access token    
    $client = new Google_Client();

    //$client->revokeToken();    
    $client->revokeToken($accesstoken);

    //Destroy entire session    
    session_destroy();
```